# Testing difference of counts of one category across a combination of the other two categories

Tags: categorical-data, ordinal-data

I am using R. I have a dataset that looks like this using `srt()`:

```r
'data.frame':   233 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Design : Factor w/ 4 levels "Crossover","Observational",..: 2 3 3 3 4 3 3 1 3 2 ...
 $ Status : Factor w/ 3 levels "Active","Passive",..: 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ Outcome: Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "Positive"<"Neutral"<..: 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 ...
```

This is the code I have run so far:

```r
c.1 <- c %>%
  transmute(Design = as.factor(Design),
            Status = as.factor(Status),
            Outcome = factor(Outcome, ordered = TRUE, 
           levels = c("Positive", "Neutral", "Negative"))) %>%
  dcast(Design + Status ~ Outcome, drop = FALSE)
```

To get the output that looks:

```r
          Design      Status Positive Neutral Negative
1      Crossover      Active        8      10        1
2      Crossover     Passive        6       4        0
3      Crossover      Posted        0       0        0
4  Observational      Active        9       4        0
5  Observational     Passive        0       0        1
6  Observational      Posted        0       0        0
7       Parallel      Active       33      32        2
8       Parallel     Passive       67      37        1
9       Parallel      Posted        1       2        0
10      Pre/Post      Active        4       0        0
11      Pre/Post     Passive       10       1        0
12      Pre/Post      Posted        0       0        0
```

**Situation:**
"Design" refers to the study designs that have been reported. "Status" refers to the way a treatment was delivered (active, passive, or posted). The Positive, Neutral and Negative are the outcomes of the intervention. The numbers below are the counts for each outcome for a given combination of Design and Status.

So for example, the combination of Crossover (Design) + Active (Treatment) gave 8 positive outcomes.

**My question:**

Which statistical test can I use to:

1. Check if there is significant difference in the nature of the outcome (Positive, neutral or negative) for a given combination of Design and Status.

I was advised to use a method to test "ordinal" factors as Positive, neutral and Negative as in our context was the same as "High", Medium" or "Low".